# Which data type to use inorder to store value in optimum way

Tags: c++, memory-management, initialization

Suppose I want to store a positive number (not greater than 10000), which data type should I use so that I allocate minimum memory for it?

I read somewhere `unsigned short int` and `unsigned int` go from 0 to 65,535

Should I use this or will a simple `int` do?

Comment: What do you mean by "store"? If it's a few local variables, just use int. Only use the small types if you are storing many of them.

Answer (score 0):

An unsigned short will consume half the memory of a signed int (2 bytes vs 4 bytes). Because the processor often needs to work on whole integers the execution might be slightly slower since it needs to unpack the shorts.

In your case you could also use a signed short, it ranges from roughly -32K to +32K.

Answer (score 0):

depends :
lets say you want to create an array of size  1000000

```
int foo[1000000] ={};//4000000 byte
unsigned short foo[1000000]={}; //2000000 byte 
//you save 2 MB of memory
```

but

```
int foo;
unsigned short foo;
//that's two bytes not much really  even when multiplied by a dozen of variables...
```